AttributeError: 'jaxlib.xla_extension.DeviceList' object has no attribute 'split'
when i run merf, some error happend,it seems like some problem with jax.
when the error happends, the trackback like this below
2024-04-10 12:15:25.092253: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-04-10 12:15:26.642827: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
I0410 12:15:26.660196 139784372380736 xla_bridge.py:863] Unable to initialize backend 'cuda': 
I0410 12:15:26.660422 139784372380736 xla_bridge.py:863] Unable to initialize backend 'rocm': module 'jaxlib.xla_extension' has no attribute 'GpuAllocatorConfig'
I0410 12:15:26.661076 139784372380736 xla_bridge.py:863] Unable to initialize backend 'tpu': INTERNAL: Failed to open libtpu.so: libtpu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
W0410 12:15:26.661236 139784372380736 xla_bridge.py:901] An NVIDIA GPU may be present on this machine, but a CUDA-enabled jaxlib is not installed. Falling back to cpu.
/home/syd/anaconda3/envs/merf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/_src/xla_bridge.py:1120: UserWarning: jax.host_id has been renamed to jax.process_index. This alias will eventually be removed; please update your code.
  warnings.warn(
Loading from COLMAP
Warning: image_path not found for reconstruction
Loading from COLMAP
Warning: image_path not found for reconstruction
jax.errors.SimplifiedTraceback: For simplicity, JAX has removed its internal frames from the traceback of the following exception. Set JAX_TRACEBACK_FILTERING=off to include these.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/syd/merf/train.py", line 562, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "/home/syd/anaconda3/envs/merf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/syd/anaconda3/envs/merf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/syd/merf/train.py", line 95, in main
    _, state, _, _, _ = train_utils.setup_model(
  File "/home/syd/merf/internal/train_utils.py", line 398, in setup_model
    model, variables = models.construct_model(rng, temp_rays, config)
  File "/home/syd/merf/internal/models.py", line 358, in construct_model
    init_variables = model.init(
  File "/home/syd/merf/internal/models.py", line 300, in __call__
    features, density = query_representation(
  File "/home/syd/merf/internal/models.py", line 182, in query_representation
    features = grid_utils.interpolate_based_on_local_coordinates(
  File "/home/syd/merf/internal/grid_utils.py", line 175, in interpolate_based_on_local_coordinates
    sparse_grid_y, y = y.split([8], axis=1)
AttributeError: 'jaxlib.xla_extension.DeviceList' object has no attribute 'split'

I have install all version of jax，but it not fix

This looks like a mismatch in the expected JAX version. This code was added in June 2023, at which point the most recent JAX release was v0.4.11. I would try running the code with that JAX version installed.
